# How to safely escape URL from user input to be used in file_get_contents?

Tags: php, url, escaping, file-get-contents, sanitize

I have simple question. User supplies URL to my PHP script where I fetch the page from the URL and parse it and show some snippet to user. Now I want to sanitize or better escape the URL so it is safe for me to fetch it by using file_get_contents().

My simplified code looks like this:

```
$url = $_POST['url'];
$html = file_get_contents($url);
```

First thing what came to my mind is to use regex for catching evil URL, but I don't think it is efficient and better would be escape the whole URL. But what PHP function can I use for escaping URL for use in file_get_contents() function ?

Comment: "Escaping" is useless here. You're looking for *validation*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply require the url to start with `http://` or `https://`.

Luckily PHP is smart enough not to follow redirects to a `file://` url.
However, it **does** follow redirects to `ftp://` urls, so you better make sure your server cannot access any internal ftp servers without authentication.

Comment: That last statement should better be tested... :)

Comment: @ThiefMaster Could you please supply some reference links for your answer (e.g. PHP not following `file://`), please ?

Answer (score 0):

And if you want to do regex, take a look here:

Stackoverflow: [What is the best regular expression to check if a string is a valid URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/161738/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-to-check-if-a-string-is-a-valid-url)